# Как проверить массив на наличие нескольких элементов

Tags: javascript

Как проверить массив `freeSeats` на наличие нескольких чисел ?
В данном коде я проверяю массив только на наличие числа 11

```js
'2023-02-17': {
        '15:00': {
            'freeSeats': [
                '11','21','31','41','50'
            ],
            'format': false,
            'food': true
        },
    }
function bob(number) {
     return seats["2023-02-17"]["15:00"].freeSeats.find((i) => {
        if (i === number) return true
    })
}
console.log(bob('11'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методами **every** и **includes**

```js
const seats = {
  '2023-02-17': {
    '15:00': {
      'freeSeats': [
        '11','21','31','41','50'
      ],
      'format': false,
      'food': true
    },
  }
}

function bob(number) {
  return number.every(el => seats["2023-02-17"]["15:00"].freeSeats.includes(el));
}
console.log(bob(['11', '21']))
console.log(bob(['11', '22']))
```

Для каждого элемента массива, переданного в функцию, должно находиться значение в массиве **freeSeats**. Если все значения найдены, вернется **true**, иначе **false**